# Django - How to remove the cached user data of the last session in Python Social Auth?

Tags: django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I'm making a sample login app with Python Social Auth.

My app provides the user the chance to login with **facebook** or **twitter**.

Let's say the name of my facebook account is **boel.facebook** and the one for twitter
is **boel.twitter**.

This is a fragment of my papeline.

```
def get_profile_picture(
    strategy,
    user,
    response,
    details,
    is_new=False,
    *args,
    **kwargs
    ):
    img_url = None
    if strategy.backend.name == 'facebook':
        img_url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' \
            % response['id']
    elif strategy.backend.name == 'twitter':
        img_url = response.get('profile_image_url', '').replace('_normal', '')


    print('THE USER IS: %s'%(user.username))
    ###
```

If the user makes login with facebook, the console prints
`"THE USER IS: boel.facebook"` 
and the app redirects to the logged page where I have a link for making logout, 
which calls the following function in views.py:

```
def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
   #redirect to login page.
```

At this point the user is back to the login page. Until here, everything is OK.

Now, if the user tries to login with twitter this time, Python Social Auth
redirects to the twitter login and after the user successfully authenticated,
the pipeline is called but the console prints:
`"THE USER IS boel.facebook"` again.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Since the user is authenticated with twitter this time, the console had to print:

```
"THE USER IS boel.twitter".
```

Please help.